# How to concatenate string with decimal?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have 2 columns in tbl_BillingTerm

1. BTTitle (VARCHAR(MAX))
2. BTBill  (money)

---

```
using (var db = new ClothEntities())
{
    var data = (from bterm in db.tbl_BillingTerm
                select new
                {
                    bterm.BTId,
                    BillingTerm = bterm.BTTitle +""+ bterm.BTBill+": USD/month"
                }).ToList();
}
```

I want to concatenate Title and the Bill as shown I coded using LINQ.
It's generating an error:

```
> "Unable to cast the type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Object'.
   LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."
```

Comment: exactly where is this exception thrown, what is the exception type?

Comment: Try explicit cast: `(string)bterm.BTBill`

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. this is exactly what i get

Answer (score 3):

instead do,

```
using (var db = new ClothEntities())
{
    var raw = (from bterm in db.tbl_BillingTerm
                select new
                {
                    bterm.BTId,
                    bterm.BTTitle,
                    bterm.BTBill
                }).ToList();

    var data = raw.Select(bterm => new
        {
            bterm.BTId,
            BillingTerm = string.Format(
                "{0} {1}: USD/month",
                bterm.BTTitle,
                bterm.BTBill)
        });
}
```

In essence, use EF to get the data then, do awkward string manipulation with linq-to-objects.

Everything after the `ToList()` will not be interpreted by the EF provider.

---

Alternatively, if you really want to do this server side you could try,

```
using (var db = new ClothEntities())
{
    var data = (from bterm in db.tbl_BillingTerm
         select new
         {
             bterm.BTId,
             BillingTerm =
                 bterm.BTTitle + " " + 
                 SqlFunctions.StringConvert(bterm.BTBill) 
                 + ": USD/month")
         });
}
```

This uses the [`SQLFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) class that the EF provider should map to the appropriate canonical TSQL function(s).

In this case I see little value in this second approach. The split solution above results in a denser result set to be transported to the client. The inter process communication is likely to have a significantly higher cost than a second iteration of the results.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [mapping to a Canonical Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx) for the int to string casting.

If this error is preventing you from progressing and is a small dataset you could could hydrate your retrieval from the database by enumerating the query (call `ToList`). From that point on, your operations will be against in-memory objects and you may not encounter the error you are receiving.

```
using (var db = new ClothEntities())
{
    var result = (from bterm in db.tbl_BillingTerm
                select new
                {
                    bterm.BTId,
                    bterm.BTTitle,
                    bterm.BTBill
                }).ToList();

    var data = result.Select(bterm => new
        {
            bterm.BTId,
            BillingTerm = string.Format(
                "{0} {1}: USD/month",
                bterm.BTTitle,
                bterm.BTBill)
        });
}
```

Comment: Essentially my answer but 6 minutes later.

Comment: but it's more explained